# 2GB RAM VPS with LAMP. How can i improve performance and loading times?

Tags: mysql, php, vps, lamp

I recently upgraded my VPS(OpenVZ VT) to 2GB of RAM. Despite the configuration changes i make to the LAMP stack the websites loading times take up to 5-10 seconds to fully load. I use prefork with apc enabled on Centos 6.3. I have installed the zpanel to add control to vhosts and i currently host a few wordpress and other sites. I would like to use it as a shared hosting enviroment. Below i provide my conf files:

Apache(/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf):

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    2
MaxSpareServers    5
ServerLimit   50
MaxClients        50
MaxRequestsPerChild 200
</IfModule>
```

MySQL(/etc/my.cnf):

```
# Fine Tuning
max_allowed_packet = 32M
thread_cache_size = 128
thread_stack = 192K
max_connections = 1000
table_cache = 1024
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 128M
query_cache_type=1
key_buffer = 64M
# End Fine Tuning
```

And just to clarify even more my question i would like to add that Google page speed insights suggest that my main issue is server repsonse.

My uptime output is load average: 0.36, 0.17, 0.11

Server version: Apache 2.2.15
MySQL version: 5.1

Though i am not experiencing any RAM issues, would it be better if i switch to Worker MPM?

Any performance improvement suggestions to make websites load faster? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i think that the added information clarifies better my question. Can the status change to normal and not "on hold" please?

Comment: Your update really doesn't clarify anything.  Since you are probably running type of web app, you are going to need to look at your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite bad for a variety of reasons

1. You don't define what "slow" is
2. You don't give any detail about what the server is running
3. You don't give any performance measurements
4. You're using a control panel, do you actually know what you're doing?

And most importantly:

You're using a VPS. There's no way you can properly troubleshoot this, as your VPS provider may simply be overloading his servers. Ask them why your server is so slow.

Comment: 1. Slow like a site takes more than five-ten seconds to load. 2. Centos 6.3 (OpenVZ) standard LAMP stack, APC enabled. 3. I will provide measurements soon. 4. I use a control panel to provide shared hosting service and to ease the process of editing and creating configuration files for every vhost.